# Using haml and erb

Tags: ruby, web-applications, haml, erb

Can haml be use as a complete replacement for erb and vice versa or are there particular cases where one should be use?

Like for example: is better do X with haml and is better to do Y with erb.

I'm trying to get as quickly as possible to my web app and don't really want to learn both right now if it can be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using HAML almost exclusively for years and on many projects. I can't remember having to convert any HAML file to ERB.

But I can think of some cases where ERB may be easier:

- When you share the templates with people who only know HTML.
- [When you write content](http://chriseppstein.github.com/blog/2010/02/08/haml-sucks-for-content/), unless you use markdown or something.
- When you import existing HTML (samples, legacy, etc.). To convert them I use `html2haml` directly in my terminal.
- When you need full control on the white spaces in the output HTML. It's rarely needed, but the HAML syntax to handle that is not great.
- When you have many ERB files to convert to HAML. Some of them cannot be parsed correctly by `html2haml --erb`.
- And obviously when you don't generate HTML. For example I use ERB to generate text emails, and in Rails generators.

Answer (score 1):

Petty sure HAML can also be used for everything. I'd recommend using ERB to get you started though. It's a lot simpler - everything is HTML until you use a <% %> or <%= %>.

No doubt someone will disagree with me.

Comment: True, but it's good idea to use HAML. Pages get away simpler to read and faster to write.

Comment: This question is clearly on of opinion, so I'm happy to reply. I dislike the processing element of HAML as I'd rather have direct control. Also I dont trust things which rely so heavily on indentation. Finally since I've been using erb for 5 years now I find that faster to read/write ;)